# tweeter4j upload image and message from android

Tags: android, twitter4j, android-twitter

Exception using trying to tweet after authentication ,
**Twitter Login Error**

if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            Uri uri = getIntent().getData();

```
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
            // oAuth verifier
            Log.d("Inside","inside");
            String verifier = uri
                    .getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

            try {
                // Get the access token
                AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(
                        requestToken, verifier);

                // Shared Preferences
                Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();

                // After getting access token, access token secret
                // store them in application preferences
                e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,
                        accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                // Store login status - true
                e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                e.commit(); // save changes

                Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());

                // For now i am getting his name only
                long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                String username = user.getName();
                Log.d("usrnm",username);
                // Displaying in xml ui

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Check log for login errors
                Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }




private void loginToTwitter() {
        Log.d("user",""+isTwitterLoggedInAlready());
        // Check if already logged in
        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            Configuration configuration = builder.build();

            TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
            twitter = factory.getInstance();

            try {
                requestToken = twitter
                        .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        } else {
            // user already logged into twitter    
            new updateTwitterStatus().execute("Hello");

        }
    }
```

stack trace

```
04-12 11:21:52.479: E/Twitter Login Error(1065): > null
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace too.

Comment: – IceMAN i have updated it

Comment: I really think you should post this as a different question. The updated question and _perhaps_ my answer changes the entire nature of the original question and will mislead future visitors. Revert to the original question, post a new question and I will try and help.

Comment: - IceMAN new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964408/exception-while-trying-to-tweet-using-twitter4j

Comment: – IceMAN i am not able to logout from my tweeter account using this tweeter 4j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is for uploading an image to Twitter via the TwitPic API. You will need to register your account in their [Developer Section](http://dev.twitpic.com/)

The solution I employ can be thought of to be a two step solution.

First, when the user clicks the post button, I first grab the Image and upload to TwitPic. From there, I grab the URL that is returned by TwitPic (`String url = upload.upload(finalFile);`).

In step two of this code, in a String instance (`String finalStatusWithURL`), I grab the content of an `EditText` and then append the URL from step 1 to it. With this done, the post is finally posted to Twitter.

```
Configuration conf = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY)
.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET)
.setOAuthAccessToken(twit_access_token)
.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(twit_access_token_secret)
.setMediaProviderAPIKey(TWIT_PIC_API)
.build();

// SET THE FILE PATH (THIS IS UPDATED! NOTICE THE CHANGES MADE!!)
Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), bmpFinal);
File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));

// THIS IS IMPORTANT. TWITPIC NEEDS THE ACTUAL / ABSOLUTE PATH OF THE IMAGE. JUST THE URI DOES NOT WORK!!!!

ImageUpload upload = new ImageUploadFactory(conf).getInstance(MediaProvider.TWITPIC);

String url = upload.upload(finalFile);
Log.e("TWITTER URL RESPONSE", url);

// END OF FIRST STEP:

// SECOND STEP IS TO UPLOAD TO TWITTER

ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(YOUR_TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(YOUR_TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(your_twit_access_token, your_twit_access_token_secret);
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

String finalStatusWithURL = null;

if (finalStatusMessage.trim().length() > 0) {

    finalStatusMessage = editStatusUpdate.getText().toString();
    finalStatusWithURL = finalStatusMessage + ":\n " + url;

} else {
    finalStatusWithURL = url;
}

twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(finalStatusWithURL);
Log.e("TWITTER RESPONSE", response.getText());
```

This is a method to get the real path of the image you want to upload:

```
// HELPER METHOD TO GET REAL PATH FOR THE SELECTED IMAGE
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); 
    cursor.moveToFirst(); 
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
    return cursor.getString(idx); 
}

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Do this before you attempt to upload:

```
Bitmap bmpFinal = getBitmapFromURL("http://www.cosmopolitanclublahore.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/mexicanfoodrestaurant.jpg");
```

And the method that return a Bitmap:

```
// THE METHOD TO DOWNLOAD THE IMAGE INTO A BITMAP
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

You may need to adapt a few things. My code uses images selected by the user from the Gallery or an image he captured with the Camera. You need to upload an image taken off the Internet. The mileage may vary and the code may need to be tweaked.

Comment: -IceMAN what is initialURI?? i am trying to Initialize it as  URI initialURI = new URI("http://www.cosmopolitanclublahore.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/mexicanfoodrestaurant.jpg"); but it is not working

Comment: @hemant: The `initialURI` is a Uri instance I use in my code. A Uri is not the same as an URL. You will need to download the Image from the URL into a Bitmap and then proceed with the code. It will need a few modifications. Give me a minute or two, to update my post.

Comment: Ok Take Your Time.. and let me know.. http://www.cosmopolitanclublahore.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/mexicanfoodrestaurant.jpg this is the url of image suppose which i need to upload to my tweeter..

Comment: -IceMAN Uri initialURI =Uri.parse("http://www.cosmopolitanclublahore.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/mexicanfoodrestaurant.jpg");
   Done this its not giving any error but at the same time nothing is tweeted on my twitter account

Comment: @hemant: That is not how it is done. Please check the updated post.

Comment: -IceMAN getImageUri() this methord is not available in your code this ?

Comment: -IceMAN Thanks dude .. also i would like to ask you have you worked on Pagerview?

Comment: @hemant: You mean the `ViewPager`? Not a lot actually. I do use it but mighty limited use. You have doubts about that?

Comment: @hemant: And, you are welcome. Glad I could help. Did the code work by the way.

Comment: Yes ViewPager, i have included 1 xml inside viewpager , and have a values in arraylist.. i want viewpager to navigate my xml based on the values of arraylist , same xml should be updated with diffrent values.

Comment: @hemant: I would suggest posting a new question for it. You will get replies from users who have used it a lot. ;-)

Comment: – IceMAN i am getting an exception Twitter Login Exception anyidea why this exception ?

Comment: @hemant: I won't be able to say without seeing your code and your actual stacktrace. Also, you should consider posting another question since they are different. I will see if I can be of help there.

Comment: – IceMAN i am using the same code, but integrated it into my current activity. its get loged it but Uri is not returing properly

Comment: @hemant: Okay. Then update the OP with the new code and it's stacktrace and let me see what I can do. ;-)

Comment: – IceMAN i have a problem could you you please help me up?

Comment: – IceMAN When i am posting some text along with image it get tweeted into my tweeter account, but when i am trying to tweet again, it doesn't get tweeted unless i delete my previous tweet.

Comment: @hemant: Nothing you can do about it. The Twitter API rejects similar posts that you post in a short span of time. Post something different every time.

Comment: – IceMAN can you help me with fetching the user details while login with facebook

Comment: – IceMAN  No authentication challenges found
 Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=ea09dc6d 
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=051c1797
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[ea09dc6d-051c1797 0237e8c8-9e66d70f], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.2} do you know why this error arrises

Comment: im getting an error while im trying to upload to the image with the answered code  :   Authorization completed with an error
                                            com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Authorize failed.